# Getting All series on a given axis must be of the same data type, with Vue + Google Spreedsheet

Tags: vue.js, google-visualization, vue-component

I used the exact example and even created the same spreedsheet as in the vue example https://codesandbox.io/embed/yqxxkp32mj?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue here, if i copy the spreedsheet from their example it works fine but when I add my own spreedsheet (which is practically a copy of what they have it gives me this error)

Getting All series on a given axis must be of the same data type
`methods: {
    onChartReady(chart, google) {
      const query = new google.visualization.Query(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GpwJaxUPYv9MV2uAvW4qkKanFlwrzTHWS55vzK3J9VE/edit?usp=sharing"
      );
      query.send(response => {
        const options = {
          title: "Creating a Chart from a Separate Spreadsheet"
        };
        const data = response.getDataTable();
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
    }
  }
};`

This is my google sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GpwJaxUPYv9MV2uAvW4qkKanFlwrzTHWS55vzK3J9VE/edit?usp=sharing

I am using vue-google-charts

Thanks

Comment: try removing the column headings in row 1

Comment: Hi WhiteHat if I do that how would I add labels? as the moment it picks those labels from the heading

Comment: does removing the column headings resolve the error? if so, we can add them back then manually change them to the headings before drawing the chart...

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat I decided to go with React and got it working, React had better tool/option to manage the spreedsheet